# The error of “The key type can't be BOOL, ANY or DICTIONARY”

Tags: sqldatatypes, dolphindb

I run the following scripts in DolphinDB database GUI:

```
x=(int128("2e8ca9773da3a99f2c87a623ac34f242"),int128("2e8ca9773da3a99f2c87a623ac34f243"))
y=1..2
dict(x, y);
```

It returns me an exception:

```
dict(x, y) => The key type can't be BOOL, ANY or DICTIONARY
```

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

x is a tuple and the data type is ANY. The key type of a dictionary can't be ANY type. To fix the issue, make sure X is a regular vector.

```
x=[int128("2e8ca9773da3a99f2c87a623ac34f242"),int128("2e8ca9773da3a99f2c87a623ac34f243")]
y=1..2
dict(x, y)
```